# Why do we need the abstract base class library when we have NotImplementedError?

Tags: python, inheritance

Here's a typical use of abstract base classes in python:

```
from abc import ABC

class MyBaseClass(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self):
        print("Here's some logic that I want all subclasses to have")

class ChildClass(MyBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("Here's some additional logic that I want this subclass to have")
```

The behavior is: it's not possible to instantiate `MyBaseClass`, but it is possible to subclass it, and `MyBaseClass` includes logic inherited by all subclasses.

Here's another way to get this same behavior:

```
class MyBaseClass:
    def __init__(self):
        if type(self) == MyBaseClass:
            raise NotImplementedError
        print("Here's some logic that I want all subclasses to have")

class ChildClass(MyBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("Here's some additional logic that I want this subclass to have")
```

As far as I can tell, this approach has the exact same behavior, has the same amount of code, is equally explicit, and uses only native Python. So what does `ABC` do that this approach can't handle?

Comment: It's better to use an ABC because type-checking with expressions like `type(self) == MyBaseClass` is unpythonic (plus it forces you to hardcode the name of a class into the class' body — which make changing the class name more work as well as more error-prone).

Comment: You wouldn't primarily make `__init__` an abstract method, you'd define other abstract methods the subclass is required to implement. So, I wouldn't call this use "typical".

Comment: `ABC` prevents `__init__` from being called at all (which happens *after* `__new__` has already created an instance of the class).

Comment: You can have classes that can be instantiated and have some methods that might get called or not in some cases, but that need to be implemented when they are called. In this case, the class should not be abstract and you should use NotImplementedError. In other cases, the class is not meant to be instantiable, in which case use ABC for reasons outlined by the other people here, or even just for code readability.

Answer (score 9):

Abstract base classes prevent you from instantiating an object unless you implement the abstract methods. This raises the error immediately and alerts you to the fact that you need to implement the method. This is especially helpful if you instantiate the class but don't call the method until after a lengthy execution process: you won't raise `NotImplementedError` until you call the method.

```
import abc

class AbstractClass(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def test(self):
        pass

class NotAbstractClass:
    def test(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class AbstractInheritor(AbstractClass):
    pass

class NotAbstractInheritor(NotAbstractClass):
    pass

x = AbstractInheritor() # raises error immediately
y = NotAbstractInheritor() # no error despite not implementing test
```

In fact, the line where I create `x` is caught by my type checker, so I do not even need to run the code to know there is a problem. Meanwhile, `y` is perfectly fine.